# What was the preferred method of holding things down in Apollo?

Tags: apollo-program, velcro, fastening

The Apollo space capsules had a ton of velocity changes - from liftoff, to separations, to reentry to splashdown, there were a lot of sporadic movements.

The capsules also needed to carry things that would be used in space. How were these things kept in place? Velcro was only a few decades old when the program started. Was Velcro used? Straps?

Comment: NASA's ubiquitous use of Velcro is what made it popular (and gave origin to the myth that it was NASA that invented it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll borrow heavily from a September 1973 Apollo Experience report called "[Crew Station Integration: Vol.IV - Stowage and the support team concept](http://history.nasa.gov/alsj/tnD7434Stowage.pdf)" by Marion W. Hix from Houston.

- Use of Velcro started during Mercury missions
- Gemini program introduced **modular containers** with molded foam holders for particular items
- **Duct tape** was used since Gemini missions
- Modular containers were fixed in place by **pip pins** or **Calfax fasteners**
- Anything not in containers could be held in place by **Velcro** (#1), **metal snaps** (#2), **utility straps**, and **bungee cords**
- After Apollo 1 fire, nylon-based Velcro was banned, and its successor found to be less efficient
- Utility straps (12 inches long - 30.4 cm) were used as a makeshift restraint where Velcro was unavailable
- Bungee cords were suggested by Apollo 10 crew (Cernan, Stafford, Young) and implemented from Apollo 11 onwards

---

Source: http://history.nasa.gov/alsj/WOTM/WOTM-Velcro.html

- Velcro had its share of problems - fouling up by dust (3 times), tiny hooks floating in the air in the Apollo 11 Command Module and irritating Collins, Velcro patch failures a total of nine times in space and in lunar EVAs.

One of the more innovative uses of Velcro included putting a patch into EVA suits to assist in scratching the astronaut's nose.