# Nose-scratching Velcro in spacesuits: hook side or loop side?

Tags: spacesuits, velcro

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/1533/26446) states

> One of the more innovative uses of Velcro included putting a patch into EVA suits to assist in scratching the astronaut's nose.

Considering that Velcro has two different textures (hook and loop) which adhere together, **which side was used for the nose-scratching patch?**

---

Update: Russian spacesuits have a [different solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valsalva_device) to the problem: a spongy piece of foam in the helmet.  It also allows the cosmonaut to hold the nose shut while blowing, allowing a hands-free Valsalva maneuver which is useful for equalizing pressure in the ears.

---

Also related:

- [How was the flammability of Velcro addressed after the Apollo 1 fire?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41993/26446)

Comment: US suits also have the Valsalva device. https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41296/6944 Note the pic in the question has both the Valsalva device and the feedport where the Velcro was attached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This close-up photo of Neil Armstrong's feedport from a [NASA webpage](https://history.nasa.gov/alsj/alsj-DrinkFood.html) appears to be hook.

OrganicMarble was therefore correct that it varies between astronauts, as a personal preference item.

[image: Armstrong's feedport]

Comment: Much, much better picture. +1 Odd that it covers the hole in the feed port.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: Another angle shows that the velcro is slit across the diameter.

Comment: Great! Consider switching acceptance to this answer, it requires no squinting.